# HPGL for HP7470a plotter

Tags: encoding, character, gnuplot

I am using gnuplot to draw a graph on a HP7470a using hpgl. This plotter is the simplified model of a HP7475a with only 2 pens. What it is also lacking is alternate character sets. Every plot I make has this hpgl code as the first line.

"IN;CA7;"

This causes my HP7470a to fall into error mode because there are only 5 alternate character sets. So only the commands CA0 CA1 CA2 CA3 or CA4 are allowed on this plotter. How do I tell gnuplot to chose one of these character sets and not CA7.

Answer (score 1):

According to the source for the hpgl terminal, the "CA7" string is emitted only if the gnuplot encoding (command `set encoding`) is set to iso_8859_1 or cp850.    I am surprised that either of those is found in the default environment of a machine 20 years into the 21st century.   Anyhow, you should be fine after setting the encoding to any of the following:

```
set encoding iso_8859_15  # successor to iso_8859_1, adds Euro symbol
set encoding default      # whatever your printer thinks is the default
set encoding cp1252       # this was the old codepage for Windows
```

Any of these will cause gnuplot not to print the `CA7` command at all.  I don't know of any way to persuade it to print `CA<something else>` instead.  Do you need the printer to handle special characters supported by one of those other settings?

Comment: Thanks Ethan, you are right I set the encoding to iso_8859_1 when I did not need to. The default value works just fine as no special characters are needed.

Comment: Good to hear.  Then you should mark the answer as "accepted" so that others can find it as a solved problem.

Comment: Ethan, I would if I knew where the accepted button was?